# how to make this SVM run faster in python

Tags: python, data-science, svm, data-mining, sklearn-pandas

I am looking for a way to make this SVM run faster. when I run this it will use all the CPU of my computer and it takes a very long time to run.

```
svcGrid = GridSearchCV(svc, 
                    cv = 4, 
                    n_jobs = 10,
                    param_grid = {'kernel':['rbf', 'linear', 
                                            'poly']})
#run the parameters tuning
svcGrid.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(svcGrid.cv_results_)

#pick and predict using the best estimators
best_svc =svcGrid.best_estimator_
print(best_svc)
y_predict = best_svc.predict(X_test)
print("BEST SVC ACCURACY:", accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about not using grid search? Grid search uses k cross-validation for parameter turning, which requires very long time.

Or, I recommend not to use polynomial kernel and linear kernel, especially polynomial kernel. Polynomial kernel requires a very very long time, and has another parameters.

Comment: you mean you recommend to not use polynomial kernel in favor of the linear kernel?